# Pageviews are not updating in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

i created blogspot in blogger http://trackanalytics.blogspot.in
i logged in to google analytics.
copied tracking id to blogger->settings->others->web tracking id
Tracking installed is the status in Admin->Tracking info.

But Page views are not updating in the report. I created goals for click events. i clicked on the links many time still there is no change in the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data isn't (always) updated in real time in Google Analytics reports.

You could either:

- Look at the real-time reports.
- Check whether data shows up 24 hours later.

Comment: thank u. i m having only 36 hours left to finish it. can u kindly check the blog post 4(i.e.links) if any mistake is there in my code.